# Facing "App not installed" error when trying to install flutter apk

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-release, flutter-apk

I am generating an APK file for the flutter app using:

```
flutter build apk
```

and it generates the following file:

> build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk

I was always able to install this apk on my phone or any other phone to test it. But recently I started getting the following warning when installing the app:

[image]

And then when I tap "Continue", I get this error: "App not installed".

Since this error is new, I though maybe that's due to a change that I recently made. And the only change that could've affected the apk file is that I regenerated the `key.jks` file which is used to sing the apk file. That file is used in the `android/build.gradle` file:

```
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('key.jks')
            storePassword '**********'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword '**********'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

What could be causing this error? I also tried "flutter clean" but that didn't help.

Comment: How do you install the app? The preferred way should be `adb install app-release.apk` then you will get a detailed error message in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the advice! This is the error: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to
extract native libraries, res=-113]`

Comment: The error means the APK does not contain the matching native libraries. For a recent physical device this should be arm64-v8a. You have to check the APK using a zip tool what libraries are included.

Comment: @Robert I checked, all three libraries are included.